# How and what to expose of an AVL Tree class for proper testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I don't know which methods should be public, because I have the test methods which require a node and a node is something which no one must know about.

```
public static class Node<K, V> //nested static class of AVLTree
public class AVLTree<K extends Comparable, V>
   public void insert(K k, V v)
   private Node insert(Node root, K k, V v)
   private Node rightRotate(Node n)
   private Node balanceFactor(Node n)
```

When it comes to testing , I actually have to create a `root` as a `node` object and create a tree without the `insert` method because `insert` is  only for `AVL trees` and not `nodes`.

The same issue applies to the other below test methods :

```
boolean isAVL(AVLTree.Node n) 
boolean isBST(AVLTree.Node n)
void rightRotate(AVLTree.Node n)
boolean isBalanceFactorGood(AVLTree.Node n)
```

Comment: C# has `[InternalsVisibleTo]`. Perhaps your language has something similar?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I believe there could be a hacky way to do in Java... creating a class without the public identifier in a package but I'm not sure if that's the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, it is beneficial to separate low-level operations from the public API of the class.

The public API has convenient method names, and provides encapsulation. For example, you might allow iteration and key lookup, but prevent direct access to the structure and layout of the tree. Clients should be able to use the data structure without knowing that it is implemented as an AVL tree. Unit tests of the API check that the tree works as expected, without making sure that the AVL-specific operations work fine.

The low-level layer implements the AVL-specific operations. Most clients should not use this layer directly, but only via the public API. This layer does not provide any encapsulation of the AVL structure, so it needs to be used correctly. It is fine if this layer uses procedural programming instead of OOP design. Although this layer isn't going to be used by other clients, it should be public so that unit tests can verify the implementation. Unit tests on this level can assert details about the tree structure, e.g. that rotations work as expected.

Note that the public API should not inherit from the lower layer: you only want to use the implementation, not inherit the interface.

Example design:

```java
// implementation details

public class Node<K, V> {
  ...
}

public class AVLDetails {
  public static <K, V> void insert(Node<K, V> root, Node<K, V> n) { ... }
  public static <K, V> void rotateRight(Node<K, V> n) { ... }
  public static <K, V> void rotateLeft(Node<K, V> n) { ... }
  ...
}

// public API

public class Tree<K, V> {
  private Node<K, V> root;
  ...
  public void put(K key, V value) {
    AVLDetails.insert(root, new Node<>(key, value));
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I believe I can use this approach for every data structure that I will impleement from now on.